# When I click on link in sms send sms to another number using php?

Tags: php

Is that possible to respond to the android application through SMS? I mean, will send SMS to the particular phone number with link and number inside the body. When user click on the link, message to be sent to the number present inside the message.

Comment: Actually I mean is sms to be sent to the phone number inside the message body.

Comment: Mobile Number is in message. Which message ?

Comment: Okay, let me be clear. I will send a push message from php to mobile. That message body contains link and mobile number which i get it from user.

Comment: now what i need to do is, when I click on the link in the message it should send message to the mobile number whick is their present at push message. Can I do it?

Comment: Yes. It will send message.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['number']))
    // send SMS to number ($_GET['number'])....
```

SMS e.g.:

```
yourwebsite.com?number=0157388764
```